# Как получить произведение элементов списка на примере

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть задание получить произведение списка на примере

```
[1, 5, 2] ==> [10, 2, 5] 
[4, 5, 2, 19, 8, 80] ==> [121600, 97280, 243200, 25600, 60800, 6080]
```

Сначала получаем произведение без учета 1 элемента затем без учета 2 элемента и далее 3,4,5,6...

Длина списка может быть разной длины.

```
def list_p(numbers: list) -> list:
    total = 1
    for elem in numbers:
        elem = int(elem)
        if elem != 0:
            total *= elem
            print(total)
```

Вот что я смог сделать. Дальше уперся в стену. Помогите. За ранее спасибо!

Comment: Код согласно правилам сайта просьба поместить.

Answer (score 2):

Например, так:

```
def list_p(numbers: list) -> list:
    total = 1
    for elem in numbers:
        total *= elem
    return[total//x for x in numbers]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает!!!)